# Actionscript 3.0 frame amination

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

need help regarding actionscript 3.0 to call an action. I am using this set of codes to get things working but nothing is moving at all. Here is the code i used:

If there is an error or anything wrong, do post and i will take a look at it, thanks a lot in advance!!!

```
if(MovieClip(Workspace).currentLabel == "NA1" && MovieClip(Workspace2).currentLabel == "NA2" && MovieClip(BalanceScalePlate).currentLabel == "NAPlate")
{
  MovieClip(Workspace).gotoAndPlay("MTT");
  MovieClip(Workspace2).gotoAndPlay("MTB2")
  MovieClip(BalanceScalePlate).gotoAndPlay("LURDFM");
}
```

Comment: where is this condition set ? (is it on a frame so should be evaluated when the frame is reached or is it set on a mouse/key press /etc.) ? You can add `trace("test");` line before that condition and run your swf. if you see "test" in the Output Panel, than that part of the code has executed, so you can move if within the condition. If you don't see the "test" message from within the if condition block, trace your condition to see if it's what you expect and change it if/when needed. HTH

Comment: Wrap each comparison in an additional pair of round brackets, should do.